# change screen rotation of app extension in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios-app-extension

How do I lock from rotating screen, I want my app extension to be only in portrait mode.
When I'm using my extension inside Photos my I can rotate the screen to landscape.

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that you app extension inherits your project settings. So lock there the screen and it will be locked everywhere

Comment: False, project settings do not seem to affect app extension orientations. Regardless of what you have checked off, iOS seems to assume everything is a valid orientation by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to choice:

1- Set landscape and portrait as supported interface orientation in the project, and then for each ViewController, you will override the supported interface orientation;

2- Set only portrait mode in the project, and in the ViewController you need it, you can make a 90 degree rotation

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

EDIT: so you can do this. Set your controller as observer for the keyPath `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`. Then:

```
-(void)changedOrientation: (NSNotification *)note
{
    if (note)
    {
        UIDevice *dev = (UIDevice *)note.object;
        if ([dev orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        }
        else if ([dev orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }
        else if ([dev orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }
        else if ([dev orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to disable landscape orientation?

Comment: Hi I am having same problem.I want to show a viewController only in landscape mode.My code works in iOS app but not in action extension any idea?

Comment: Hello, I'm also finding this doesn't work in App Extensions. UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification isn't being fired, it would seem.